# How to parse multiple pdfs to text from a folder in Java

Tags: java, pdf

I have a folder with a lot of pdfs and I need to convert them all to txt and save those text files in another folder. I want to use java for this.

I have this code to parse a pdf but it only works for one at a time and I need to process a folder with thousands of pdfs.

```
 PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
 PDDocument pdDoc = null;
 COSDocument cosDoc = null;
 File file = new File("C:/my.pdf");

 try {
     PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
     parser.parse();
     cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
     pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
     pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
     pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
     pdfStripper.setEndPage(20);
     String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
    }catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Put the above code in a loop that iterates the files.

Comment: Try using a folder name, and a `listFiles()` method instead of one file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
PDDocument pdDoc = null;
COSDocument cosDoc = null;
String parsedText=""; // append the text to this every time
File folder = new File("/yourFolder"); // put all the pdf files in a folder
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); // get all the files as an array

    for (File file : listOfFiles) { // cycle through this array 
        if (file.isFile()) { // for every file
             try { //do the same 
                 PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
                 parser.parse();
                 cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
                 pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                 pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
                 pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
                 pdfStripper.setEndPage(pdDoc.getNumberOfPages()); // if always till the last page
                 parsedText += pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc) +  System.lineSeparator(); // append the text to the String
                }catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
               } 
       }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!  As a follow up I was wondering if there is a way to save the new parsed files separately instead of one large text file.

Comment: I am glad I could help :) you can save the "parsedText" after every loop into a file text instead of appending it to the text

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that